# Cannot convert webm video and audio to mp4

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, javascript

I am trying to record video and audio in canvas using RecordRTC and converting it to mp4 but getting below error. Please suggest me the command for ffmpeg to fix the issue.

```
Received command: -i video.webm -i audio.webm -c:v mpeg4 -c:a aac -b:v 6400k -b:a 4800k -strict experimental output.mp4.  Processing with 268435456 bits.
configuration: --cc=emcc --enable-cross-compile --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --cpu=generic --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-a`enter code here`sm --disable-doc --disable-devices --disable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --disable-network --disable-hwaccels --disable-parsers --disable-bsfs --disable-debug --disable-zlib --disable-protocols --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs --enable-protocol=file --enable-pic --enable-small
libavutil      52. 52.100 / 52. 52.100
libavcodec     55. 41.100 / 55. 41.100
libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
libavfilter     3. 90.102 /  3. 90.102
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
[vp8 @ 0xcba330] Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'video.webm':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 300x400, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Metadata:
alpha_mode      : 1
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'audio.webm':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo (default)
[graph 1 input from stream 1:0 @ 0xccf4c0] Invalid sample format (null)
Error opening filters!
Finished processing (took 3688ms)
{"type":"done","data":[{"name":"output.mp4","data":{}}],"time":3688}
{"name":"output.mp4","data":{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ffmpeg is ancient. You omitted the version info but it appears to be from late 2013 or early 2014. This was before there was an Opus decoder.

FFmpeg development is very active so you're missing out on many features and bug fixes. Update to a modern version and it should work.